# Cannot combine the resulting libraries using the lipo command

Tags: objective-c

Going to develop an `iOS VoIP` app as my final project, but not finding a proper `SDK`  to be used for making app to work like `Skype/ Viber`, for Voice and Video Call.

Or suggest me another FREE library.
I working on this from the previous 2 months...
Thanks.

EDIT: 
[image]

When I perform 'lipo' command this occurs:

```
iMac-2:lib mac$ lipo -arch libpj-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a  -arch libpj-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a  -arch libpj-armv7s-apple-darwin_ios.a -arch libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0.a  -create -output libpjlib.a
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: unknown architecture specification flag: libpj-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a in specifying input file -arch libpj-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a -arch
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: known architecture flags are: any little big ppc64 x86_64 x86_64h arm64 ppc970-64 ppc i386 m68k hppa sparc m88k i860 veo arm ppc601 ppc603 ppc603e ppc603ev ppc604 ppc604e ppc750 ppc7400 ppc7450 ppc970 i486 i486SX pentium i586 pentpro i686 pentIIm3 pentIIm5 pentium4 m68030 m68040 hppa7100LC veo1 veo2 veo3 veo4 armv4t armv5 xscale armv6 armv6m armv7 armv7f armv7s armv7k armv7m armv7em arm64v8
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo [input_file] ... [-arch <arch_type> input_file] ... [-info] [-detailed_info] [-output output_file] [-create] [-arch_blank <arch_type>] [-thin <arch_type>] [-remove <arch_type>] ... [-extract <arch_type>] ... [-extract_family <arch_type>] ... [-verify_arch <arch_type> ...] [-replace <arch_type> <file_name>] ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got errors in library means, Either you have not properly configure the PJSIP project in Your system (or) you missed any library that you want to add in your xcode project.

If you want to run project in simulator or iphone?
There is two different configuration for pjsip project. For iphone and simulator, configuring project is different.

For properly configure your PJSIP Project in your system, follow this below link.

Source : https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

Please post the error message completely in your xcode, to solve the problem.

Comment: Okay I try it again

Comment: Please help me to understand how to define PJ_AUTOCONF=1 in the Xcode's project config.

Comment: lipo command is used for to run your project in both simulator and iphone. It's combination of two builds. If, it's not working simply build for either simulator or iphone to test your project.

Comment: click your xcode project target and select Build settings, and select Apple LLVM 8.0-Preprocessing in the list , and add PJ_AUTOCONF=1 in Preprocessor Macros value field.

Comment: offcourse @Eesha .Post your future questions here in the comment. I will give solutions to solve it.

Comment: @Eesha its showing something related to Audiosession error. when running your app, while you are initiating any audio session like making new call, this error occurs. right? If it is true means, then follow my answer in following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989940/ios10-iphone5s-voip-siphon-pjsip2-5-5-error-opening-sound-device/41181949#41181949

Answer (score 1):

You missed architecture name

**was:**

```
lipo -arch libpj-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a -arch libpj-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a ...
```

**Need:**

```
lipo -arch arm64 libpj-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a -arch armv7 libpj-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a ...
```

For each **-arch** you need set **name** and than lib name